# How to Stop Hackers Sending my Express Server Offline?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, security, nginx

I created a Digital Ocean Droplet on Ubuntu, installed Nginx with Express Server acting as a proxy. It also uses Node and React JS. Sometimes when I wake up in the morning, I'll notice that I can only see the body background colour on my front-end app and the React login form is not showing. The console log then shows `502 Bad Gateway`. At first, I thought this was just a rare occurrence, but it's been happening more recently. Please understand I'm extremely new to all of this, so I hope you can understand what I'm saying.

Looking at my Nginx logs, it looks as though somebody is trying to request files from my server:

[image]

I'm not exactly sure how this is sending my Express server offline (I'm assuming that's what it's done), but I really need to avoid this.

Could anybody please help me understand how I avoid this from happening? Or if these requests are normal and I'm looking in the wrong place, how I can identify why this is knocking my server offline?

Thanks so much, I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how you start you express application but if you start it with node command it can crash in some time. Instead, it's better to use tools for production like [pm2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2) or [forever](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever)

For example to run:

```
pm2 start app.js -i max
```

With this solution app will auto restart on crash. My advice is to add logs to you application specially on Errors that crash application for this reason use [Winston](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston)

Comment: Sorry, yes, I use pm2 to start my server. I'm sorry for not mentioning this. I thought using pm2 would resolve this issue, but it still crashes. I can't see anything that helps in the pm2 logs. Maybe I'm looking at this wrong? Maybe it's not the Express server that's crashing perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

It's not this which put your express server off.

When you see the log it's only 4/5 request per second with return 301 HTTP code for 194 octet (request don't seems to be transmitted to your express app). Nginx can handle much more.

Even if it's not the main cause, if you want to block it (php extension) put this in your nginx conf file :

```
location ~ (\.php) {
    return 403;
}
```

To check if your problem comes from node or nginx (i assume that nginx run on port 80 and node on port 3000) just launch a curl request on both.

```
curl -X GET -vI http://localhost:9000/myapp => If HTTP code 502 problem comes from your app

curl -X GET -vI http://localhost:80/myapp => If HTTP code 502 and previous request works, your nginx server do a wrong redirection of the request
```

You problem probably comes from your express app. A route is probably crashing down your app or you have a memory leaks with put your server down after some times.

You can check memory leaks easily by sending thousand of request to your server (100 000 here, 5 concurrent) :

```
ab -n 100000 -c 5 http://badasse.com/
```

During this, check with top the memory used by your node/pm2 process, it must stay  constant

Comment: Thank you, this information is very useful. I'll take a look and see what I can do.

Comment: When using curl on port 9000, I receive "Operation timed out". Port 80 works fine. I checked the status of Nginx and it is `active`. So this means it's definitely the Express server right? When I run `pm2 logs`, it won't show me the logs (permission denied) it looks like pm2 is crashed also. How do I check the memory whilst I run `ab -n 100000 -c 5 http://badasse.com/`? Thank you

Comment: When I run `pm2 list`, it still shows the app as `online`. Does this mean it's Express only? The app is fine? Another thing to note, this only happens when I'm asleep. Not when I'm using the app/testing during the day, this is why I thought it was hackers over night.

Comment: 9000 was an example, you can found your port with "ps aux | grep node" port is in the first value. ab -n ... runs 100000 request by batch of 5 to adress http://badasse.com/, replace this adresse by your server adress (http://localhost:80/myroute1), if you crash is due to memory leak you will see it with it

Comment: Sorry, of course, I thought my port was 9000 but it was 3000 - I will check that again next time it is down. I ran the command for testing memory leaks and received this: `apr_pollset_poll: The timeout specified has expired (70007)`. Thanks for your help here.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into [helmetjs](https://github.com/helmetjs/helmet)

The readme states:

> Helmet helps you secure your Express apps by setting various HTTP
>   headers.

Comment: Thank you, I will look at this.